# Using a class as argument of a custom worksheet function

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a custom worksheet function that uses a class that I have defined as argument. I have tried to do the following:

I created a class named Wrapper:

```
Private m_value As Integer

Public Property Get value() As Integer
  value = m_value
End Property

Public Property Let value(value As Integer)
  m_value = value
End Property
```

Then I wrote two functions:

```
Function make_wrapper(value As Integer) As wrapper
  Set make_wrapper = New wrapper
  make_wrapper.value = value
End Function

Function square(wrapper As wrapper) As Integer
  square = wrapper.value * wrapper.value
End Function
```

If I chain those function directly from VBA, everything works as I expected

```
Sub doit()
  MsgBox (square(make_wrapper(7)))
End Sub
```

displays 49.

If I try to call the function directly from excel it does not work. If I type "=square(make_wrapper(7))" in a cell, it displays "#VALUE!". What am I doing wrong? Is this possible at all?

Comment: It seems `square` is never called with those two formulas like that - maybe Excel stops immediately when it receives a non-standard value in a formula? You could define a separate function that is a function to essentially return `square(make_wrapper(foo)) as integer` instead (which will work, even from an Excel sheet).

Comment: Yes, but that is exactly what I do *not* want to do. I want to use this to structure very complex arguments to the function and have some "type safety" by using different classes as arguments.

Comment: I expect Excel doesn't like the type `wrapper` returned from the first function `make_wrapper` in a UDF. Try re-writing to output a known type such as `Variant`

Comment: Just noticed your also trying to pass type `wrapper` in function square. I'm almost certain this can't be done via a UDF.

Comment: The `make_wrapper` call sort of works - if you set a breakpoint in the code and enter `=make_wrapper(7)` in a cell you can see that the code runs OK, but the cell only displays `#VALUE!`. The call to `square` fails directly, a breakpoint in the code is never reached. Conclusion: it seems @ooo is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seems no one has given you a definitive answer.

> Is this possible at all?

You cannot return a custom type to a UDF like that.

Try this instead:

```
Function square(iValue) As Integer
    Dim w As New wrapper

    w.value = iValue

    square = w.value * w.value
End Function
```

Though I'm not sure exactly what your trying to achieve with the class module.

Answer (score -1):

The parameter name isn't valid: 'Wrapper' is already the name of a class.

Try This:

```
Function square(MyWrapper As wrapper) As Integer   
    square = MyWrapper.value * MyWrapper.value 
End Function
```

Comment: If you are unable to offer detailed information on how it failed - outputs, error messages, warnings from the compiler - then I cannot assist you. I think your best course of action is to read up on some of the basics - parameter-passing in VBA, how UDFs work, using Option Explicit - and begin again with a simpler programming task.